# MFC WebBrowser Control: How many (normal) lines of code does it take to simulate Ctrl+N?

Tags: c++, internet-explorer, mfc, webbrowser-control, hosted-app

**Update:** Answer: Two normal lines of code required. Thanks Noseratio!

I banged my head on the keyboard for more hours than I would have cared to trying to simulate IEs Ctrl+N behavior in my hosted Browser control app. Unfortunately, due to complications which I've abstracted out of my code examples below, I can't just let IE do Ctlr+N itself. So I have to do it manually.

Keep in mind that I am running a hosted browser. So typically, opening links in new windows will actuall open it within a new "tab" within my application (it's not really a tab, but another window... but appearance-wise it's a tab). However, Ctrl+N is different -- here, it is expected a fully-fledged IE window will launch when pressed.

I think my problem is that of framing the questions -- admittedly I am new to WebBrowser control and I find it to be a lot of yucky. Regardless, I've scoured the Internet for the past day and couldn't come up with an elegant solution.

Basically, the ideal solution would be to call a "NewWindow" function within WebBrowser control or its affiliate libraries; however, all I was able to find where the **On**NewWindow methods, which were event handlers, not event signallers. Which I understand that most of the time, the user will be creating the events... but what about programmatic simulation?

I tried looking into an SENDMESSAGE approach where I could use the IDs that the OnNewWindow events use... that ended up in nothing than crashes. Perhaps I could go back to get it work, but I'd like confirmation is that approach is even worth my time.

The next approach, which *should have* been the most elegeant, but sadly didn't pan out, was like the following:

```
Navigate2(GetLocationURL().GetBuffer(), BrowserNavConstants::navOpenInNewWindow);
```

It would have worked marvelously if it weren't for the fact that the new window would open in the background, blinking in the taskbar. needing clicking to bring it to the front.

I tried to get around the limitation in a myriad of ways, including getting the dispatcher of the current context, then calling OnNewWindow2 with that IDispatch object. Then I would invoke QueryInterface on the dispatch object for an IWebBrowser control. The webBrowser control (presumably under the control of the new window) could then navigate to the page of the original context. However... this too was a pretty messy solution and in the end would cause crashes.

Finally, I resorted to manually invoking JavaScript to get the desired behavior. Really?? Was there really no more elegant a solution to my problem than the below mess of code?

```
        if ((pMsg->wParam == 'N') && (GetKeyState(VK_CONTROL) & 0x8000) && !(GetKeyState(VK_SHIFT) & 0x8000) && !(GetKeyState(VK_MENU) & 0x8000))
        {
            LPDISPATCH pDisp = CHtmlView::GetHtmlDocument();
            IHTMLDocument2 *pDoc;
            if (SUCCEEDED(pDisp->QueryInterface(IID_IHTMLDocument2, (void **)&pDoc))) 
            {
                IHTMLWindow2* pWnd;
                pDoc->get_parentWindow(&pWnd);
                BSTR bStrLang = ::SysAllocString(L"JavaScript");
                CString sCode(L"window.open(\"");
                sCode.Append(GetLocationURL().GetBuffer());
                sCode.Append(L"\");");
                BSTR bStrCode = sCode.AllocSysString();
                COleVariant retVal;
                pWnd->execScript(bStrCode, bStrLang, retVal);
                ::SysFreeString(bStrLang);
                ::SysFreeString(bStrCode);
                pDoc->Release();
            }
            pDisp->Release();
```

I find it hard to believe that I must resort to such hackery as this to get something as simple as opening a new window when the user presses Ctrl+N.

Please stackoverflow, please point out the clearly obvious thing I overlooked.

Comment: Just wondering: have you considered calling CreateProcess() to open iexplore.exe with your URL?

Comment: Are you looking to have the new window opened in a separate process (iexplore.exe)? You should be aware it will run on a separate HTTP session, so user may need to relogin into the same website.

Comment: Hmmm, I'll have to explore that idea. It does on its face seem fairly elegant. The goal is simulate Ctrl+N in IE, so if a separate HTTP session is what happens in IE when one presses Ctrl+N, then good, otherwise not good. My feeling is that the IE Ctrl+N makes an exact replica of the current session in the new window -- however, since all tabs run with their separate processes nowadays, it's difficult for me to put a stamp of authority on that statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ctrl-N in IE starts a new window on the same session. In your case, `window.open` or `webBrowser.Navigate2` will create a window on a new session, because it will be run by `iexplore.exe` process which is separate from your app. The session is shared per-process, this is how the underlying `UrlMon` library works. So you'll loose all cookies and authentication cache for the new window. On the other hand, when you create a new window which hosts `WebBrowser` control within your own app process, you'll keep the session.

If such behavior is OK for your needs, try first your initial `Navigate2` approach, precededing it with [AllowSetForegroundWindow(ASFW_ANY)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms632668%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) call. If the new window still doesn't receive the focus correctly, you can try creating an instance of `InternetExplorer.Application` out-of-proc COM object, and use the same `IWebBrowser2` interface to automate it. Below is a simple C# app which works OK for me, the new window is correctly brought to the foreground, no focus issues. It should not be a problem to do the same with MFC.

```
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace IeApp
{
    public partial class MainForm : Form
    {
        // get the underlying WebBrowser ActiveX object;
        // this code depends on SHDocVw.dll COM interop assembly,
        // generate SHDocVw.dll: "tlbimp.exe ieframe.dll",
        // and add as a reference to the project

        public MainForm()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void NewWindow_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            AllowSetForegroundWindow(ASFW_ANY);
            // could do: var ie =  new SHDocVw.InternetExplorer()
            var ie = (SHDocVw.InternetExplorer)Activator.CreateInstance(Type.GetTypeFromProgID("InternetExplorer.Application"));
            ie.Visible = true;
            ie.Navigate("http://www.example.com");
        }

        const int ASFW_ANY = -1;
        [DllImport("user32.dll")]
        static extern bool AllowSetForegroundWindow(int dwProcessId);
    }
}
```

Comment: Fantastic!

AllowSetForegroundWindow(ASFW_ANY) appears to have worked!

Bravo! I just *knew* there was an easier way.

As far as the separate sessions go, yes, I recall now that this would be a technical limitation of the program... which is easily explainable by the fact that the hosted browser app runs with a different process image than iexplorer.exe.

Anyway, thanks much for the suggestion!

Comment: AllowSetForegroundWindow really fit the bill of the "clearly obvious thing I overlooked" too... perfect answer!